# Create bitmask based on a pattern as constexpr

Tags: c++, c++11, bit-manipulation, c++14, constexpr

I would like to implement a template function which generates bitmasks in compile-time for integral types. These masks should be based on 8-bit patterns where the pattern will be repeated consecutively to fill the integer. The following example does exactly what I want but in run-time:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstring>

template<typename Int>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<Int>::value, Int>::type
make_mask(unsigned char pattern) {
    Int output {};
    std::memset(&output, pattern, sizeof(Int));
    return output;
}

int main() {
    auto mask = make_mask<unsigned long>(0xf0);
    std::cout << "Bitmask: '" << std::hex << mask << "'" << std::endl;
}
```

The output of the code above is:

```
Bitmask: 'f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0'
```

I know that the optimizer can eliminate the entire function call in the code above, but I'm looking for a `constexpr` solution with [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) and optionally with [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Intuitively, I'd make a byte repeater:

```
template<class Int, int count, int byte>
struct byte_repeater;

template<class Int, int byte>
struct byte_repeater<Int, 1, byte> {
    static const Int value = byte;
};

template<class Int, int count, int byte>
struct byte_repeater {
    static const Int value = (byte_repeater<Int, count-1, byte>::value << CHAR_BIT) | byte;
};
```

An easy to use interface:

```
template<class Int, int mask> 
struct make_mask {
    static const Int value = byte_repeater<Int, sizeof(Int), mask>::value;
};
```

And this works in C++03. Maybe even older.
[Compilation Here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a9171654f72a0e44).

In newer versions of C++, there's probably ways to make this simpler. Heck, even in C++03, it can probably be simplified.

Comment: Your example works with `C++98` too. I think the `byte_repeater` is not necessary, its `count` parameter in primary template can be initialized as `count = sizeof(Int)` then the `byte_repeater` can be used in the same way as `make_mask` if the `count` is the last parameter. Nevertheless it's a good point making separate templates to hide `count` parameter which is only an implementation detail.

Comment: Despite the other answers was helpful too and hard to choose the one to accept, I accept this one because of backward compatibility.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure there's a well-defined solution for signed types.  For unsigned types, I'd go with:

```
template<class Int>
constexpr typename std::enable_if</* std::is_integral<Int>::value && */ std::is_unsigned<Int>::value,
Int>::type make_mask(const unsigned char pattern) {
    return ((std::numeric_limits<Int>::max() / std::numeric_limits<unsigned char>::max()) * pattern);
}
```

This should work provided that `std::numeric_limits<Int>::max()` is a multiple of `std::numeric_limits<unsigned char>::max()`; you could add a check for that to the `std::enable_if` condition and use another solution if that check fails.

Comment: Nice solution! But I suppose that if you check for `std::is_unsigned` you can avoid to check for `std::is_integral`. I mean: the SFINAE part could be simplified as `typename std::enable_if<std::is_unsigned<Int>::value,
Int>::type`

Comment: Does `std::is_unsigned<Int>::value == true` imply that `std::is_integral<Int>::value == true`?  I can believe that, but I didn't see that guarantee during my brief searching.

Comment: According to ccpreference, `std::is_unsigned` is `true` only for "unsigned integer types and the type bool"; maybe fail for the type `bool`.

Comment: hehe, using division for creating the repeater pattern is one of my favourite tricks http://smallissimo.blogspot.fr/2011/07/revisiting-sieve-of-erathostenes.html, so this will be my favourite answer!

Comment: Excellent solution! Combined with the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45226096/7893951) given by @Justin it can be used with signed integral types too, and works with `C++11` as well. I like how you used division to generate pattern repeater.

Comment: The issue with `signed int`s is that constructing the mask might push a 1 into or through the sign bit (or simply overflow), immediately triggering undefined behavior.

Comment: In this case bitwise OR between `signed` and `unsigned` integrals might help? Let's say `int foo = int{} | std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max()` is a well-defined behavior? Can I use this to bitwise convert an `unsgined` integral to `signed` integral?

Comment: My concern is that `0x01010101 * 0x80` and similar constructions (like the one in the accepted answer) won't be well-defined if `sizeof(int) == 4` and `INT_MAX < 2147483648`.
It may be able to directly construct the desired mask as an `unsigned int`, but we'd still need to `return` it as an `int`, thereby forcing an implementation-defined conversion.

Comment: Assuming that `std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max() > std::numeric_limits<int>::max()`, your statement `int foo = int{} | std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max();` will yield an implementation-defined value in `foo`, the right-hand-side being an `unsigned int` that won't fit into an `int`.

Answer (score 4):

You can just write it out:

```
template<typename Int, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<Int>::value>>
constexpr Int make_mask(unsigned char pattern) {
    constexpr auto numBytes = sizeof(Int);
    Int result = 0;

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < numBytes; i++) {
        result |= static_cast<Int>(pattern) << (i*8);
    }

    return result;
}
```

<sup>[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/974f47a65aa9699b)</sup>

This only works for unsigned types, but you can make it work for signed types by calling the unsigned version and casting it to the signed type:

```
template<typename Int, std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<Int>::value && std::is_unsigned<Int>::value, int> = 0>
constexpr Int make_mask(unsigned char pattern) {
    constexpr auto numBytes = sizeof(Int);
    Int result = 0;

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < numBytes; i++) {
        result |= static_cast<Int>(pattern) << (i*8);
    }

    return result;
}

template<typename Int, std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<Int>::value && std::is_signed<Int>::value, int> = 0>
constexpr Int make_mask(unsigned char pattern) {
    return static_cast<Int>(make_mask<std::make_unsigned_t<Int>>(pattern));
}
```

<sup>[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2e0ea24f052d05ae)</sup>

Comment: I like how your solution handles the `signed` and `unsigned` integral types. A very easy to understand solution for `C++14` and above. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 2):

What about declaring `make_mask()` as `constexpr`, modify it adding a default parameter, using shift-bit, bit-or and recursion?

I mean

```
#include <climits>
#include <iostream>

template <typename Int>
constexpr typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<Int>::value, Int>::type
      make_mask (unsigned char pattern, std::size_t dim = sizeof(Int))
 { 
   return dim ? ((make_mask<Int>(pattern, dim-1U) << CHAR_BIT) | pattern)
              : Int{};
 }

int main ()
 {
   constexpr auto mask = make_mask<unsigned long>(0xf0);
   std::cout << "Bitmask: '" << std::hex << mask << "'" << std::endl;
 }
```

P.S.: works with C++11 too.

Answer (score 1):

It's just a multiplication. Also, you will want to make sure you don't run into any traps:

- defend against `is_integral<bool>` being true
- this function has a completely different meaning in any machine that doesn't have a 8 bit byte, so just refuse to compile for those machines
- defend against signed overflow, so just use `uintmax_t`

Stuffing all these checks onto the function signature is unreadable, so i used `static_assert()`:

```
template <typename IntType>
constexpr IntType
make_mask ( unsigned char pattern )
{
    static_assert ( CHAR_BIT == 8, "" );
    static_assert ( std::is_integral<IntType>::value, "" );
    static_assert ( not std::is_same<typename std::decay <IntType>::type, bool>::value, "" );

    enum : uintmax_t { multiplier = std::numeric_limits <uintmax_t>::max ( ) / 0xFF };
    return static_cast <IntType> ( pattern * multiplier );
}
```

Answer (score -3):

do you really need all these complications? How about just using a macro for this?

```
#define PATTERN(A) 0x##A##A##A##A##A##A##A##A

cout << hex << PATTERN(f0) << endl;
```

will work in c++98 (and in plain 'c' without cout) :-)

or if you really want to c11/++, this also works:

```
constexpr long long int pattern(const long long unsigned  pattern)  {
    return (pattern << 56) | (pattern << 48) | (pattern << 40) 
           | (pattern << 32) | (pattern << 24) | (pattern << 16) 
           | (pattern << 8) | pattern ;
}
```

Comment: This is a crappy solution but it certainly works.  I don't get why there are downvotes.

Comment: @HenriMenke Because it's not a solution; it only does it for one of the integer types.

Comment: this works for the type requested in the question. BTW, this is the most efficient solution from the compilation efficiency. Well, it has its own drawbacks, like no scoping, but it is lightweight and is straight forward.

Comment: The OP ask for a "template function which generates bitmasks in compile-time for integral types", not for a specific type and not for a fixed size type.